# OpenLayers GetFeatureInfo for GeoServer Layer Groups

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I've created  a GeoServer layer group. I'm using `OpenLayers.Layer.WMS` to retrieve the layer group, and this works fine. In addition, I'd like to pull feature info for the layer. For this, I'm using OpenLayer's `GetFeatureInfo`. But the `GetFeatureInfo` only returns feature info for only one of the layers in the layer group. Is there a way I can retrieve feature info for both layers in the group? And, is this an optimal way of dealing with layer groups?

A section of my code is shown below:

```
    var layer_group = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Sample Layer Group",
        "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms",
        {layers: "layer_group_name", transparent: true},
        {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: false}
    );
    map.addLayers([layer_group]);
```

to retrieve the layer group.

And:

```
    map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {
        var url =  layer_group.getFullRequestString({
            REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
            EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
            BBOX: layer_group.map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
            X: e.xy.x,
            Y: e.xy.y,
            INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
            QUERY_LAYERS: layer_group.params.LAYERS,
            WIDTH: layer_group.map.size.w,
            HEIGHT: layer_group.map.size.h});

        window.open(url,
                "getfeatureinfo",
                "location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,width=600,height=150"
            );
    });
```

To retrieve the feature info.

My environment setup: GeoServer 2.1.3, PostGIS 1.5, OpenLayers 2.11.

EDIT: The features shown are only for one layer
[image]

Increasing `FEATURE_COUNT` only increases the number of instances(rows) returned. The instances are over 1M. What I'd like to achieve is have one row having feature info for all the layers in the layer group.

Comment: have you managed to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to achieve what you want with a single request, a new custom behavior would need to be added that only gets only record for each layer. This would require coding, changing the GeoServer GetFeatureInfo code paths to handle a new vendor option (we cannot have such behavior by default, it's probably against the WMS spec).

The only thing I can think of is to know what layers are in the group and issue a separate GetFeatureInfo for each of the layers separately

Answer (score 3):

GetFeatureInfo by default (per WMS standard) just returns one result, if you want more add FEATURE_COUNT to your request, e.g.:

FEATURE_COUNT: 50

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea how I can retrieve features for all the layers in the layer group?

Comment: `FEATURE_COUNT` only returns more features for the one layer. Feature info for the other layers in the group are not returned, regardless of the value of `FEATURE_COUNT`.

Comment: Do you have more than 50 features in the first layer? I've just tried a GetFeatureInfo in the GS preview and I can get features from all the layers in the sample layer groups

Comment: I've edited the question above to reflect what I'm getting as I increase the `FEATURE_COUNT`. What I'd like is have one row, for instance, having information for each of the layers forming the layer group. Or, perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way. I'll be grateful for an advice.

Answer (score 0):

according to [geoserver wms docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) you can use `query_layers`:

```
var layerlist = "layer1:inci,layer2:cableline"
var url =  layer_group.getFullRequestString({
        REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
        EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
        BBOX: layer_group.map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
        X: e.xy.x,
        Y: e.xy.y,
        INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
        QUERY_LAYERS: layerlist,
        WIDTH: layer_group.map.size.w,
        HEIGHT: layer_group.map.size.h});
```

Comment: How can this even be syntactically correct when the quotation isn't even closed?

Comment: This is actually the correct answer.  Yes he did forget a double quote to close the last statement but just add it.